# My objects are passing null from Ajax to php

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel

I'm trying to pass some data from JS to PHP through Ajax, but I'm getting an error while using my data because they are null.

The problem concerns the two objects: `Debut` and `Fin`.

My JS code:

```
$('#CodeFinition').change(function(){

    var periode=$("#Période").val();
    var DebutFin = periode.split(' - ');
    var Debut = DebutFin[0];
    var Fin = DebutFin[1];
    var marque = $("#CodeMarque").val();
    var modele = $("#CodeModele").val();
    var finition = $("#CodeFinition").val();



    $.ajax({
        url:"home/Calculer?Debut:"+Debut+"&Fin:"+Fin+"&Marque:"+marque+"&Modele:"+modele+"&Finition:"+finition,
        method:"GET",

        cache : false,
        processData: false,
        success:function(result)
        {

            $("#CommandePasses").data('easyPieChart').update(result);
            $('span', $("#CommandePasses")).text(result);
        }

    })



});
```

My controllor code:

```
public function Calculer( Request $request )

{

    if(isset($request))
    {
        $marque = $request->get('marque');
        $modele = $request->get('modele');
        $finition = $request->get('finition');
        $Debut = $request->get('Debut');
        $Fin =$request ->get('Fin');


        $TotalAproduire = 100;

        $Commande = DB::connection('sqlsrv2')->table('Commande_nadine')
            ->join('finition','Commande_nadine.CodeFinition','=','finition.CodeFinition')
            ->where('finition.CodeFinition',"=",$finition)
            ->where('finition.CodeModele','=',$modele)
            ->where('Commande_nadine.DATE_DOCUMENT_CMD_ACHAT_FRS',">",$Debut)
            ->where('Commande_nadine.DATE_DOCUMENT_CMD_ACHAT_FRS',"<",$Fin)
            ->where('finition.CodeMarque','=',$marque)
            ->count('Commande_nadine.RECID_NADIN');
        $PourcentageCommandee=($Commande/$TotalAproduire)*1000;

        return $PourcentageCommandee ;



    }
    else
    {
        echo "failed";
    }

}
```

When going to my URL to test, I get this error: `InvalidArgumentException
Illegal operator and value combination.` and My home page sends a `500 internal server error`.

Can you help to solve this?

Comment: A word of advice. Always make sure that you stick with the proper letter casing.

Comment: sorry didn't get your advise

Comment: The variable you're sending are starts with capital letter `"&Marque:"+marque+"&Modele:"+modele` but you are expecting `marque`, `modele` ...

Comment: I fixed that but still not working ! This problem is in Debut and Fin which are date!

Comment: The problem is your URL syntax is invalid for query strings. See my answer for specific details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The problem is you are passing your data as query string parameters but you aren't following the correct syntax for query strings.**

This is why you are getting an HTTP response error code of 500 and an error message that says `InvalidArgumentException
Illegal operator and value combination.`

The reason is you wrote this:

```
url:"home/Calculer?Debut:"+Debut+"&Fin:"+Fin+"&Marque:"+marque+"&Modele:"+modele+"&Finition:"+finition
```

But it should be written like this:

```
url:"home/Calculer?debut="+Debut+"&fin="+Fin+"&marque="+marque+"&modele="+modele+"&finition="+finition
```

---

In short, the `:` operand (which is sometimes used for declaring object values in JavaScript) is not valid query string syntax. Also note that query strings in PHP resolve to named vars in the `$_GET` array super global, which is what Laravel is using when you call `$request->get('<variable name>');`

**So the proper rules for forming your query string are:**

1) Open the query string with the `?` operator

2) Followed by the first variable name

3) Followed by an `=` operator

4) Followed by the variable's value

5) Any subsequent variable declarations are declared in the same format as steps 1 to 4 except the `?` operator is replaced with an ampersand `&` operator

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, remove your variable naming inconsistency. **DO NOT MIX VARIABLE NAMING LIKE YOU DID, YOU HAVE ONE THAT STARTS CAPITAL AND ONE THAT DOESN'T!** That's prone to errors.

I've refactored your php to all lower case variables, and return json - so it will be javascript friendly:

**PHP:**

```
if(isset($request))
{
    $marque = $request->get('marque');
    $modele = $request->get('modele');
    $finition = $request->get('finition');
    $Debut = $request->get('debut');
    $Fin =$request ->get('fin');


    $TotalAproduire = 100;

    $Commande = DB::connection('sqlsrv2')->table('Commande_nadine')
        ->join('finition','Commande_nadine.CodeFinition','=','finition.CodeFinition')
        ->where('finition.CodeFinition',"=",$finition)
        ->where('finition.CodeModele','=',$modele)
        ->where('Commande_nadine.DATE_DOCUMENT_CMD_ACHAT_FRS',">",$debut)
        ->whereDate('Commande_nadine.DATE_DOCUMENT_CMD_ACHAT_FRS',"<",$fin)
        ->whereDate('finition.CodeMarque','=',$marque)
        ->count('Commande_nadine.RECID_NADIN');

        $PourcentageCommandee=($Commande/$TotalAproduire)*1000;

    return response()->json($PourcentageCommandee);

}
else
{ //return error response with 500 code
    response()->json("failed", 500);
}
```

Instead of sending your data in the URL as query, put in the the `data` property. It will be sent as body data. Please also `console.log(data);` before Ajax to make sure it has the correct values. I have also provided explanation in the code, it is self explainable I hope.

**JS:**

```
    var periode=$("#Période").val();
    var DebutFin = periode.split(' - ');
    var Debut = DebutFin[0];
    var Fin = DebutFin[1];
    var marque = $("#CodeMarque").val();
    var modele = $("#CodeModele").val();
    var finition = $("#CodeFinition").val();

    const data = {debut, fin, marque, modele, finition};

    // check if the output is correct! Illegal operator error means you may have done 
    // an operation that cannot be done to the datatype. E.g. multiplication, division etc 
    // on a non number datatype
    console.log(data);

    $.ajax({
        url:"home/Calculer", //remove that ugly URL an pass it as data body instead
        method:"GET",
        data: data,  //data body
        cache : false,
        datatype: "JSON",
        processData: false,
        success: function(result)
        {
            console.log(result);
            $("#CommandePasses").data('easyPieChart').update(result);
            $('span', $("#CommandePasses")).text(result);
        },
        error: function(err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    });
```

Comment: This way would also work. As would sending the data as a POST request and changing the way that Laravel receives the data.

Comment: @adis I guess the problem is mainly situated in the where('Commande_nadine.DATE_DOCUMENT_CMD_ACHAT_FRS',">",$debut) because DATE_DOCUMENT_CMD_ACHAT_FRS and debut are date, but debut is sent as a string and date retrieved from Database is considered as a string two so the comparison between them using > and < is illegal! Can you help to solve this ?

Comment: Is your date in DB using date datatype? Try casting $debut to a date. whereDate function compares date.

Answer (score 0):

if it's an ajax call route why don't you just make it a post request and send your data easily.
`$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: success,
  dataType: dataType
});`

and you can make your data like this

```
var myData = {
   id: '{{ $myPost->id }}',
   somethingElse: '{{ $someOtherThing }}'
}
```

Comment: You changed his request method to a `POST` request but his code for receiving the data won't work for data in the `$_POST` array super global. This is because in Laravel using `$request ->get(<var name>);` only resolves data in the `$_GET` array super global

Comment: well he can get it with `$request['foo']` I don's see any problem what so ever

Comment: Looking at his code you will see that is not how he is receiving the parameter currently because he is using `$request->get(<var name>)`.  If anyone tries to use your code without also making the corresponding changes in the Laravel controller it won't work and this is confusing.